# Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)

Tags: python, pyspark, command-prompt, rdd

I am getting this error while running `rdd.first()`, after running `rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])` in command prompt.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (LAPTOP-6IIGK4P5 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
```

attaching the screenshot for this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4hOa.png)

Comment: Please remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): do not post pictures of text, put that text in your post, with code markdown. Also, if you get errors, show the ([mcve]) code that generates that error in your post so others can run it and see the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69068762/3238085  : Basically use Java 8 to be on the safer side.